# How to detect if the device possess an sdcard?

Tags: android

I forsee that my application will require the existence of a sdcard storage device.
How do I query the device for a manifest of storage options ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getExternalStorageState()`.  The developer site ([linked here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)) has a short snippet of the recommended way to check for the presence of the external SD card, and whether or not you can write to it.

Comment: It doesn't quite address the question. Is there any way to determine if the device is equipped with SD Card slot to support additional external memory. The answer doesn't address the scenario where device supports the external SD Card but it is not currently mounted.

Comment: I have the same problem right now, and this solution doesn't work, the method `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` always return `false`. Also i have used the API 11 method `Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()` and always returns `true`, with or without the SD card inside the phone, i need to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

This is working and very easy to understand

```
 TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdcardstatus);
  if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))   {
  state.setText("SD card is present");
} else {
 state.setText("SD card is not present");
 }
```

Or refer on this [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/detect-sd-card-present-or-not.html)

HAPPY CODING!

Comment: This always return `true` with phones with built-in external storage