# verify and acess Micro SDCARD

Tags: android

How can i check Micro SDCARD is present in device and how i can access that to write some files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if the device possess an sdcard ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578913/how-to-detect-if-the-device-possess-an-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your device to the computer and mount your micro sd card.
Then you can go ahead and transfer the files like you do for any normal USB drive.

Comment: No, I want this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are several StackOverflow postings on these issues.

You want to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to the SD Card. You can then do standard Java File I/O.

[Android how to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory)

You must use the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[Permission to write to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card)

Comment: I know that. I am talking if you have SDCARD and MICRO SDCARD both on your device..

Comment: @user692708, your original question doesn't mention anything about what you've stated in this comment thread. Do you honestly expect a detailed answer from a vague, 1 sentence question?

Comment: I am having Samsung Galaxy TAB and it's not theoretical.

Comment: @user692708, I think you are confusing Internal storage with SD Card external storage. We still don't understand what your question is. What are you asking? You still haven't updated the original question.