# Android SD card slot detection

Tags: android, detection, sd-card, slot

Is there a way to detect if a device has an external card slot or not. I want to use internal memory if device has no slot. (Or not a functional slot like Xoom). But if the device has a card slot, even if there is no card inside I want to be able to detect it.

Is it possible with Android?

Comment: Out of interest, how will you use this information?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered at Stackoverflow: [How to detect if the device possess an sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578913/how-to-detect-if-the-device-possess-an-sdcard)

You should Google your question better next time.

Comment: I want to know if there is a working "slot" even if there is no card available.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the original poster wants to detect the slot itself, not the card inside it.